# Faster way to "distribute" values of an ndarray into other ndarrays based on assignments?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Generally, I'm trying to split a distance matrix into `K` folds. Specifically, for the `3 x 3` case, my distance matrix might look like this:

```
full = np.array([
    [0, 0, 3],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0]
])
```

I also have a list of randomly generated assignments, the length of which is equal to the sum over all elements in the distance matrix. For the `K = 3` case, it might look like this:

```
assignments = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

I want to create `K = 3` new `3 x 3` matrices of zeros, in which the values of the distance matrix are "distributed" according to the assignments list. Code is more precise than words, so here's my current attempt:

```
def assign(full, assignments):
    folds = [np.zeros(full.shape) for _ in xrange(np.max(assignments) + 1)]
    rows, cols = full.shape
    a = 0
    for r in xrange(rows):
        for c in xrange(cols):
            for i in xrange(full[r, c]):
                folds[assignments[a]][r, c] += 1
                a += 1
    return folds
```

This works (slowly), and in this example,

```
folds = assign(full, assignments)
for f in folds:
    print f
```

returns

```
[[ 0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

as desired. However, my current attempt is very slow, especially for the `N x N` case for `N` large. How can I improve the speed of this function? Is there some numpy magic that I should be using here?

One idea I had was converting to a [sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) matrix and looping over nonzero entries. This would only help a bit, however,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add.at` to do unbuffered in place operation:

```
import numpy as np

full = np.array([
    [0, 0, 3],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0]
])

assignments = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0])

res = np.zeros((np.max(assignments) + 1,) + full.shape, dtype=int)

r, c = np.nonzero(full)
n = full[r, c]

r = np.repeat(r, n)
c = np.repeat(c, n)

np.add.at(res, (assignments, r, c), 1)

print(res)
```

Comment: Nice -- I didn't know universal functions like `add` had an [at](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) modifier. Also, for anyone else who's going down the same route as me, I found the the `nonzero` method for sparse matrices helpful, here.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to figure out what item in the flattened output would get incremented each time, then aggregate them with `bincount`:

```
def assign(full, assignments):
    assert len(assignments) == np.sum(full)

    rows, cols = full.shape
    n = np.max(assignments) + 1

    full_flat = full.reshape(-1)
    full_flat_non_zero = full_flat != 0
    full_flat_indices = np.repeat(np.where(full_flat_non_zero)[0],
                                  full_flat[full_flat_non_zero])
    folds_flat_indices = full_flat_indices + assignments*rows*cols

    return np.bincount(folds_flat_indices,
                       minlength=n*rows*cols).reshape(n, rows, cols)

>>> assign(full, assignments)
array([[[0, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

You may want to print out each of those intermediate arrays for your example, to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Cool use of bincount. I ended up choosing the other, since add.at seems more direct.

Comment: The only problem with `add.at` is that it is typically dreadfully slow: wouldn't be surprised if using `bincount` turns out to be 10x faster.